# Obtaining the sum of an array list that contains complex decimals

Tags: java, math, arraylist, bigdecimal

I'm brand new to to Java and looking with some help. I have an array list as follows:

```
double number[]={19.1904990290,27.2646233344,51.4850317134}
```

I've used the following code to sum the array list and print it to the console:

```
int sumLeft = 0;        
System.out.println("Contents of leftside: " + number);
for(double i: number) sumLeft += i;
System.out.println("sum(left) = " + sumLeft);
```

and my result is 97. My question is how can I carry this out so my answer is correct?

Comment: Use a `double` rather than an `int`?

Answer (score 1):

Define `sumLeft`  as `double`. This will fix your issue.

Under the hood `sumLeft += i;` did something like

`sumLeft = sumLeft + (int)i`;

Therefore the problem you saw.

Answer (score 0):

Defining sumLeft as a double will solve your problem.

Be aware though that doubles in computer terms have limited precision and will represent your numbers in odd ways. If precision is important you need to use things like `BigDecimal`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

Answer (score 0):

As you likely know, `int` means "integer", i.e. whole numbers with no fractional component. Languages will sometimes do implicit type-conversion, so when the variable storing the value is, for example, an `int` when your numbers are of type `double`, the portion after the decimal point gets chopped off.

As others have said, changing `sumLeft` to a double will avoid this.